# Как, используя библиотеку vlc-qt, получить кадр из видео?

Tags: vlc, qt, c++

Здравствуйте.

Как с помощью `vlc-qt` получить, например, `QImage`?

В простой libvlc это делается с помощью структуры `ctx` и функции `lock`.

Предполагается, что `VlcMediaPlayer` будет отображать видео на виджите и где-то раз в секунду кадр будет обрабатываться посредством `OpenCV`.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, никак, т.к. vlc-qt просто отправляет дескриптор окна виджета, предназначенного для вывода видео, непосредственно в libvlc. Используйте libvlc напрямую для доступа к видеобуферу.